# Implementing Real Time Chat between mobile and web platforms through .NET web services

Tags: xmpp

My team works on an application that exists on both web and mobile (native iOS and Android) platforms.

The web app and the web services are written in C# and the data (SQL Server) goes back and forth through SOAP web services.

We currently have a chat feature that periodically checks for new messages, but we want to convert it to a real time chat system where messages get pushed as they are sent. I've been reading about the XMPP protocol and its different flavors but given the set up we currently have (mobile/web talking through .NET web services) how would we approach this?

Any pointers? Tutorials? Examples?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) librarly. It is very well suitable for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Could we use this on iOS and Android? I see there's a client for Xamarin but would that work for native apps.

Comment: @marianoa yes, there're multiple native clients like for example https://github.com/DyKnow/SignalR-ObjC and https://github.com/erizet/SignalA